# Concrete types and abstract types in Java when compared to other languages

Tags: java, javascript, python, oop, object

I am preparing for my finals and trying to solve exercise problems on the back of the textbook when i came across this question:

> In Java, if the concrete type of p is Foo, p.getClass() and Foo.class
>   will return the same thing. Explain why a similar equivalence could not
>   be guaranteed to hold in Ruby, Python, or JavaScript.

Can anyone shed some light on this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any context? (e.g. declaration of `Foo`)

Comment: @tom there is no context. This is a general question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby, Python and JavaScript are all dynamically typed languages, but this is not a question of static vs. dynamic typing. Rather, I think it is to do with the fact that Java's `getClass()` is final (cannot be overridden) while the other languages do not have such restrictions:

```ruby
# Ruby
class Foo
  def class­()
    retur­n Strin­g
  end
end
String.new().class() == String # => true
Foo.new().class() == Foo # => false
```

```python
# Python
class Foo: pass
class Bar: pass
p = Foo()
p.__class__ == Foo # => True
p.__class__ = Bar
p.__class__ == Foo # => False
```

```js
// JavaScript
function Foo() { }
function Bar() { }
var p = new Foo();
p.constructor == Foo; // => true
p.constructor = Bar;
p.constructor == Foo; // => false
```

Interestingly, in Python's case setting the `__class__` member actually affects method lookup so it could be argued that the concrete type of `p` is now `Bar`, which does not violate the equivalence.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is strongly typed vs weakly typed programming languages. In Java (or C++, C#, VB etc.) a type must be explicitly defined at compile time. So let's say you have a class in Java that looks like this:

```
class Foo{
    String a;
    public void DoNothing(){}
}
```

The moment you hit the compile button, your class is fixed; you cannot change it at runtime. That is to say, let's say you have a variable p, which is an instance of Foo, you cannot do:

```
p.b = 12345;
```

The compile will yell at you. And you know FOR SURE, p will have a property called "a", it HAS to be a String, and a method DoNothing() which returns no type.

JavaScript, on the other hand, does not have a concept of a "class", because you can dynamically add (or remove) properties or fields to an object at runtime. So you can do:

```
var x = {}; //declares a new object, it is empty right now
x["name"] = "Hello World!";
x.doWork = function() { ... };
```

The result is, you will not know whether the variable "x" contains the field called "name" or a function called "doWork" until the moment you execute that line at runtime.

Same argument applies for Python and Ruby.

Comment: In your javascript example the concrete type of `x` is not `Foo`, so how is that "a similar equivalence"?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what is asked.

If you have in python

```
class Foo(object):
    pass

p = Foo()
```

then `p.__class__` would return `Foo` as an object. The class name could be printed with

```
p.__class__.__name__
```

or on class

```
Foo.__name__
```

Of course in python you can do something like this

```
class Foo2(object):
    pass

p.__class__ = Foo2
```

But yes, it's dynamic language.

So the last option is quite rare and in general I can't see difference.

Comment: In Ruby you can do even better: `class Foo; def class() return String end end`

Comment: @tom: well... you see... I don't like _that_ better;) But it's definitely not the topic here.

Comment: I was a bit hesitant about that Python example because it appears to actually change the type of `p`. In my Ruby example the concrete type clearly doesn't change because methods defined in `Foo` still work on `p`.

Comment: @tom: yes, it changes type. Actually your example is't so... monkey-patching as mine. And this is what I don't like - monkey-patching. In bad hands it could be very destructive.